# How to grant execute permissions to the stored procedures in a specific schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there a way in SQL Server 2012 to grant execute all stored procedures in one schema?
For additional info, these stored procedures are doing just a select.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try something like that. It creates a new role and grants execute permission to a schema.

```
CREATE ROLE db_executor
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::schema_name TO db_executor
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_executor', 'Username'
```

Replace `schema_name` with your schema and `'Username'` with your user.

Comment: Is it possible to GRANT SCHEMA permission to an already exists SQL SERVER role such as db_datareader?

Comment: @FatihYarbaşı It should be possible but I'm not sure about built-in roles. I would advise against extending built-in roles, it's better to create your own custom one.

Answer (score 3):

For granting execute permission for all of the stored procedures in one schema , the query by 
@szymon is enough.

The below query will grant execute permission for the procedure to the user selected.
Provided the user already exists.

> GRANT EXECUTE
>       ON OBJECT::[schema].[procedurename] TO [user]
>       AS [schema]; 
>   GO

Answer (score 1):

I’d recommend you do what Szymon suggested since it’s more elegant solution but it you want to avoid creating roles you can execute query like this, copy results into separate query editor and execute all at once.

This will generate GRANT EXECUTE statements for all stored procedures you have in specific schema

```
DECLARE @SchemaName varchar(20)
DECLARE @UserName varchar(20)

SET @SchemaName = 'dbo'
SET @UserName = 'user_name'

select 'GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::' + @SchemaName + '.' + P.name  + ' to ' + @UserName
from sys.procedures P
inner join sys.schemas S on P.schema_id = S.schema_id
where S.name = @SchemaName
```

Comment: But what if new stored procedures will be created? I think you need to grant exec permissions for newly created stored procedures as well?